# selenium python problem with loading page driver.get('http://page.com/') open empty window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/firefox')
browser.get("http://google.com/")
```

Ubuntu 16 LTS user here.How to fix this empty window issue after I enter url and is no loaded page there.

Output:

```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/calculator/test.py", line 781, in <module>
>     browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/firefox')   File
> "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/calculator/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 164, in __init__
>     self.service.start()   File "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/calculator/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 98, in start
>     self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/calculator/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 111, in assert_process_still_running
>     % (self.path, return_code) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
> /usr/bin/firefox unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `geckodriver` path not firefox.  Check your firefox browser version and you can download compatible geckodriver from [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path of geckodriver")
```

Sample code

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/username/Location/geckodriver")

browser.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: Thank you.It`s up and running . Just I move it in  /usr/local/bin/ after untar.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the path to your webdriver in the `PATH` system variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/driver/firefox-driver
```

Add it to /home//.profile file to make it permanent.

Then you dont need executable_path=''

Comment: Where do you see `chrome` in the question?